# How can I install libssh2?

Tags: php, ssh, libssh

I need to install a CMS, but this CMS requires the libssh2 library.
When I try to install it according to the instructions, I get errors.

Here I will give the places with errors:

```
$ sudo tar zxvf libssh2-1.4.3.tar.gz
$ cd libssh2-1.4.3.tar.gz
c485186@ryzhikov:/home/libssh2-1.4.3$ sudo ./configure
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating example/Makefile
config.status: creating docs/Makefile
config.status: creating libssh2.pc
config.status: creating src/libssh2_config.h
config.status: creating example/libssh2_config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
configure: summary of build options:

  version:          1.4.3
  Host type:        x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Install prefix:   /usr/local
  Compiler:         gcc
  Compiler flags:   -g -O2
  Library types:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Crypto library:   openssl: yes (AES-CTR: yes) libgcrypt: no
  Debug build:      no
  Build examples:   yes
  Path to sshd:     /usr/sbin/sshd (only for self-tests)
  libz compression: yes

c485186@ryzhikov:/home/libssh2-1.4.3$ sudo make & sudo make innstall
[1] 3120
Making all in src
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/libssh2-1.4.3/src'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/libssh2-1.4.3/src'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I../include -I../src   -g -O2 -MT channel.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/channel.Tpo -c -o channel.lo channel.c
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/libssh2-1.4.3/src'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -I../include -I../src   -g -O2 -MT channel.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/channel.Tpo -c -o channel.lo channel.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../include -I../src -g -O2 -MT channel.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/channel.Tpo -c channel.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/channel.o
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I../include -I../src -g -O2 -MT channel.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/channel.Tpo -c channel.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/channel.o
```

And here I see a lot of errors.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the errors that you are getting?

Comment: Yes, but it is a lot of chars.

Comment: http://john-studio.org/log.txt